# Import multiple excel sheets into SQL Server tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, asp.net-mvc

I have about 20 files, all with 20 or more sheets. I need to import specific data from all sheets into tables (as the same columns as the table). My code only imports one sheet. How to import multiple sheets? And how to import specific cells from Excel? I have read many questions but none do what I need and the most are old

Database is SQL Server. I hope you can help me. I'm a newbie.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
{
        string filePath = string.Empty;

        if (postedFile != null)
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");

            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            filePath = path + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
            postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

            string conString = string.Empty;

            switch (extension)
            {
                case ".xls": //Excel 97-03.
                    conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                    break;

                case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 and above.
                    conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
                    break;
            }

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            conString = string.Format(conString, filePath);

            using (OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conString))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter odaExcel = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

                        //Get the name of First Sheet.
                        connExcel.Open();
                        DataTable dtExcelSchema;
                        dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                        string sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                        connExcel.Close();

                        //Read Data from First Sheet.
                        connExcel.Open();
                        cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "]";
                        odaExcel.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
                        odaExcel.Fill(dt);
                        connExcel.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Constring"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {
                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                {
                    //Set the database table name.
                    sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Table_1";

                    //[OPTIONAL]: Map the Excel columns with that of the database table
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Rut", "Rut");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Nombres", "Nombres");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Malla", "Malla");

                    con.Open();
                    sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: My suggestion is to import it all, and *then* weed out what you don't need.

Comment: I second that. And also go and have a good cry before hand because you are going to need it part way through. Importing Excel files is one of the most annoying things to do because excel sheets are almost never consistent. People just cant help themselves. I always bring it into a single table first then worry about working it all out once I'm there.

Comment: but knows a class , library or something ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you are going to get SQL Server to do this, and if you can get C# to do it, it will probably be magnitudes harder.  I mean, you have options like this...

```
SELECT * INTO XLImport5 FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\test\xltest.xls', 'SELECT * FROM [Customers$]')
```

That will import everything from a sheet named 'Customers' (you need to keep that $ character in there).  Hopefully there is some kind of consistent pattern between all those Excel files, but I am just guessing about that.  Anyway, if I were you I would install the AddIn from the link below.  Follow the GIU and aggregate your data in Excel, as it will almost certainly be a lot easier to manipulate in that environment.  Then...send it from Excel to SQL Server.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

[image]